# Hide many div after click on button form

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

In this part of code I have several forms generated automatically by thymeleaf, each of which allows you to vote for a web location, now I would like that once you click on a question of a specific web location, the others automatically hide from the view.

For example, if I have 3 web locations and vote for a web location question with id = 2, web locations with id = 1.3 hide automatically.

```html
<div th:each="childLocation : ${childLocations}"> 
  <form th:action="@{/sendVote}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" 
     data-successHandler="afterOpinionSent" class="s_ajaxForm" th:object="${childLocation}">
    <input type="hidden" name="webLocationId" th:value="${childLocation.id}" th:if="${childLocation!=null}"/>
  <div th:each="webQuestion : ${@webQuestionRepository.findByWebLocation(childLocation.id)}" class="row sinWebQuestion" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div th:text="${webQuestion.question}" class="sinButtonVoteLabel" style="text-align: center;">How Do?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">
   <label th:each="vote : ${ {3, 2, 1, 0} }" class="radio-inline sinButtonVote" style="margin-top: 10px;">
   <input type="radio" th:name="|questionVote[${webQuestion.id}]|" th:value="${vote}" />
    <img yada:src="@{|/res/img/question/${webQuestion.iconName+vote}.png|}" th:alt-title="|Vote ${vote}|">
   </label>
  </div>
  </div>    
       <button th:id="|sendVoteButton${childLocation.id}|" type="submit" class="s_ajaxForm btn btn-default btn-block hidden">Send Opionion</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I try to use inline javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
 /*<![CDATA[*/
 $(".sinButtonVote > img").click(function(e){
 $(this).parents("div.sinWebQuestion").addClass("voteChosen");
 $("#sendVoteButton[(${childLocation.id})]").removeClass("hidden");
 $("#sendOpinion[(${childLocation.id})]").removeClass("hidden");
     
  /*[# th:each="n : ${childLocations}"]*/
    if([(${n.id})]!=[(${childLocation.id})]) {
     $("#sinVoto[(${childLocation.id})]").hide()
   /*[/]*/
 });
 function afterOpinionSent() {
   $("div.sinVotoInner").addClass("hidden");
  }
 /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Once you click on the question hide all div.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Attach a class to all of the elements and hide that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
            /*<![CDATA[*/               
function hiddenFunction(xId){
            var userInput = document.getElementById("webLocationId"+xId).value;
            document.getElementById("userInputId").innerHTML = userInput;
            /*[# th:each="n : ${childLocations}"]*/
                if([(${n.id})]!=userInput) {
                    $("#sinVoto[(${n.id})]").addClass("hidden");
                }
            /*]]>*/
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(".sinButtonVote > img").click(function(e){
        $(this).parents("div.sinWebQuestion").addClass("voteChosen");
        $("#sendVoteButton[(${childLocation.id})]").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#sendOpinion[(${childLocation.id})]").removeClass("hidden");

        /*[# th:each="n : ${childLocations}"]*/
        if([(${n.id})]!=[(${childLocation.id})]) {
            $("#sinVoto[(${childLocation.id})]").hide()
         /*[/]*/


    /** this is the new code **/
        }

        afterOpinionSent();
    });

    /** end of new code **/

    function afterOpinionSent() {
            $("div.sinVotoInner").addClass("hidden");
        }
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I've added an extra `}` to close the img click callback function, and I also call your `afterOpinionSent` function because this was not being called.

Comment: I try to use it, but i have this error log: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: in this line code: `$("#sinVoto25").hide()
            
           });`

Comment: the problem was here `/*[/]*/
    /** this is the new code **/
        }` , the new extra } must be added before /*[/]*/, but also in this case after i click all the div form hide. I would like to only the div on i to be click was visible and the others hide.